# Bootstrap accordion looping through posts incorrectly

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page on my website - https://visitwinona.com/ask-a-local/

Where I'm calling all the categories of my custom post type faqs, I've implemented the bootstrap accordion, and it works but as I added a new category the last accordion opens a random one instead of the one it's meant to. I see that it's using the same ID for some reason but I'm unsure how to solve this,

```
<?php
 /*
   * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
 */

 $post_type = 'faqs';

 // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
 $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type 
  ) );

 foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

// Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>





        <?php
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug,
                    )
                )

            );?>



            <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                  <?php echo $term->name; ?> +
              </a>
            </h2>




         <div id="collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if( $c == 1 ) echo 'in'; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>">


            <?php $localfaqs = new WP_Query($args);?>



           <?php if ( $localfaqs->have_posts() ) : while ( $localfaqs->have_posts() ) : $localfaqs->the_post(); $c++; ?>


           <div class="row">    
               <?php 

                   $faqs = get_field('local');

                        if( $faqs ): ?>
                            <?php foreach( $faqs as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>


                                   <div class="col-md-half faq-circle">
                                        <div class="celeb-circle-faq">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ); ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>



                <div class="col-md-10 faq-link">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <?php the_title();?>
                    </a>
                </div>


           </div>


    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>



<?php endforeach;

  endforeach; ?>
```

Any advice would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `the_ID()` to give an ID to each taxonomy term, but `the_ID()` doesn't output the ID of the current term in a foreach loop, it get's the ID of the current *post*.

Since you're not resetting postdata in your custom queries this will be the ID of the last post of the previous term.

To give a unique ID to each accordion, use the term's ID with `$term->term_id`:

```
<?php
/*
 * Loop through Categories and Display Posts within
 */
$post_type = 'faqs';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,  //show all posts
            'tax_query'      => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term->slug,
                )
            )

        );
        ?>

        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $term->term_id ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?> +
            </a>
        </h2>

        <div id="collapse-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if( $c == 1 ) echo 'in'; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>">

            <?php $localfaqs = new WP_Query( $args );?>

            <?php if ( $localfaqs->have_posts() ) : while ( $localfaqs->have_posts() ) : $localfaqs->the_post(); $c++; ?>
                <div class="row">    
                    <?php 
                    $faqs = get_field('local');

                    if ( $faqs ) : foreach ( $faqs as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) 
                        ?>

                        <div class="col-md-half faq-circle">
                            <div class="celeb-circle-faq">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

                    <div class="col-md-10 faq-link">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                            <?php the_title();?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

What I changed was `collapse-<?php the_ID(); ?>` to `collapse-<?php echo $term->term_id ?>` and `heading-<?php the_ID(); ?>` to `heading-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>`.

I also added `wp_reset_postdata();` after the custom query loops, so that any code coming after the loop isn't referencing the incorrect post.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was something to do with that I just couldn't get my head round it. That's worked perfectly!